# translating a string with html elements in it

Tags: magento2, php, localisation, translate

I'm having trouble translating this string in M2. It has '' element in it, I have tried all possible string splitting options but none of them seems to work. Is there some kind of a trick that I don't know?

```
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('<span class="label">Order Date:</span> %1', '<date>' . $block->formatDate($block->getOrder()->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::LONG) . '</date>') ?>
```

I need to translate that **Order Date: %1** part

I hope it hasn't been asked before, though I didn't find an answer for it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your csv language file

```
"<span class=""label"">Order Date:</span> %1","<span class=""label"">Translation here</span> %1"
```

Notice the doubled double quotes around "label".